# Why SpringMVC Request method 'GET' not supported?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I trying `@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)` but is error

Code is

```
 @Controller
 public class HelloWordController {
 private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloWordController.class);

 @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String welcome() {
  logger.info("Spring params is welcome");
  return "/WEB-INF/jsp/welcome";
 }

}
```

web.xml is

```
<servlet>
<description>This is Spring MVC DispatcherServlet</description>
<servlet-name>SpringMVC DispatchServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
  <description>SpringContext</description>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>classpath*:springmvc.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

```
  <servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>SpringMVC DispatchServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

and springmvc.xml is

index.jsp is

```
<form action="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/test" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="submit"> 
</form>
```

I input submit botton brower is error

> HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET'
>   not supported  type Status report
>
> message Request method 'GET' not
>   supported
>
> description The specified HTTP method
>   is not allowed for the requested
>   resource (Request method 'GET' not
>   supported).

Comment: Do you see the log message in the welcome() method?

Comment: I'm still unclear about how to resolve this, there is no good answer here. No one explained why we can't do RequestMethod.POST. Can someone follow up? I don't understand any of the comments.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Change

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

To

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Comment: Why does `method=RequestMethod.POST` not work? The form method is POST and the action URL is /test, so I would have thought it will work.

Comment: @WebUser it is a myth, some says tomcat disables it by default, so they have to apply filter in web.xml but what if a dev is making an API with SPRING Boot framework, even today in 2016/March it is giving same error, but Using GET works clean and perfect in address bar.! 

Answer would be that one has to make whole panel then write Ajax calls to Delete/Put/Post to work.!

Answer (score 30):

`method = POST` will work if you 'post' a form to the url /test.

if you type a url in address bar of a browser and hit enter, it's always a `GET` request, so you had to specify POST request.

Google for `HTTP GET` and `HTTP POST` (there are several others like PUT DELETE). They all have their own meaning.

Comment: this is by far the cleanest explanation of why my Spring API gives 'GET' not supported when i am using RequestMethod.DELETE in my Controller.!

Comment: This does not solve the issue, it just explains basic knowledge. The "Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported]" always appears when sending a form via POST.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently some POST requests looks like a "GET" to the server (like Heroku...)

So I use this strategy and it works for me:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/salvar", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
```

Comment: Could this cause any security issue to add RequestMethod.GET to a RequestMethod.POST form (i.e. login form) ?

Comment: method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST } is considered as security hotspot in SonarQube. Its betted to use GET or POST at a time. Avoid to use both together.

Answer (score 4):

For me the problem was that I forgot to add a protocol to baseUrl in my postman request. After I've added "https://", it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this error by including a get and post request in my controller:
method={RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET}

Answer (score 1):

Are you working with Angular? I had the same problem and it was because I was using subscribe and they changed their implementation (This deprecation was introduced in RxJS 6.4.) It worked for me using it like this:

import { of } from 'rxjs';

// recommended
of([1,2,3]).subscribe((v) => console.info(v));

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. I changed it to the following and it worked.

Java :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

HTML code:

```
  <form action="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/test" method="GET">
    <input type="submit" value="submit"> 
    </form>
```

By default if you do not specify http method in a form it uses GET. To use POST method you need specifically state it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: so why do you specifically state "GET"?

Answer (score 0):

if You are using browser it default always works on get, u can work with postman tool,otherwise u can change it to getmapping.hope this will works

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by including json data into postman body part and then hit the postmapping url

Answer (score 0):

For me dosn't work I put solution abowe, You have to implement whole path like it's on pictures. Good luck

As well don't forget use:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class RoomService {
```

[image]

[image]

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{roomId}/status/{status}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> changeRoomStatus(
            @PathVariable int roomId,
            @PathVariable RoomStatus status) {

        try {
            roomService.changeRoomStatus(roomId, status);
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Room status changed successfully.");
        } catch (RoomNotFoundException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body("Room not found.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                    .body("Error changing room status: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```