# Request method 'GET' not supported Exception for GET requests

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am getting following exception in production often even for GET Services but i am getting 200 as status code for respective service, i don't how it's happening. can you please get me back any one know about it. Thanks

```
 org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:203) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:352) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:299) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:57) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:299) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1104) [spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:916) [spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877) [spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966) [spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857) [spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624) [servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842) [spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) [servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:438) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:179) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:190) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.62]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.62]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.62]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [?:1.7.0_72]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [?:1.7.0_72]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.62]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_72]
```

Comment: Got any code to accompany this error? show us your request mapping statements. Here is a common error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333611/why-springmvc-request-method-get-not-supported

Comment: Is someone hitting a URL that is POST only?

Comment: Even for get also same error is comming