# Spring Boot Rest Service | Request method 'GET' not supported

Tags: java, jquery, html, rest, spring-boot

I have made a hello world rest service using spring boot.
I am able to call the service via standalone java program. I am also able to call it via [Advanced Rest Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?hl=en-US) add-on for Chrome.

But when I try to hit it via a standalone HTML page using jQuery AJAX I am getting error

> WARN 3748 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'GET' not supported

Any Help is appreciated.

> PS: I am assuming that as I am able to call the WebService using other
>   modes so the controller is fine. But something is wrong the way I am
>   calling it from the HTML.

**HTML Page Below:**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Client</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.2.3.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#Submit").click(function() {
        var input = {
          "name": $("#name").val(),
          "language": $("#language").val()
        };
        var inputStr = JSON.stringify(input);
        alert(inputStr);
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://localhost:9000/rest/greetMeObj/",
          method: "POST",
          data: inputStr,
          dataType: "jsonp",
          success: function(output) { // callback method for further manipulations
            var str = JSON.stringify(output);
            $("#output").text(data);
          },
          error: function(data) { // if error occured
            $("#error").text(data);
          }
        });

      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="input">
    <label><b>Name:</b>
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" alt="Enter you name" title="Enter your name" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <label><b>Language:</b>
    </label>
    <select name="language" id="language" title="Select your language">
      <option value="en" label="English" selected="selected">English</option>
      <option value="fr" label="French">French</option>
      <option value="nl" label="Dutch">Dutch</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br />
    <button title="Submit" type="button" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" formaction="POST">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <div id="output"></div>
  <div id="error" style="color: red;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Spring Controller Below**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/rest/*")
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String TEMPLATE_EN = "Hello, %s!";
    private static final String TEMPLATE_FR = "Bonjour, %s!";
    private static final String TEMPLATE_NL = "Hallo, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping(value="/rest/greetMe", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Greeting sayHello(
            @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "Stranger") String name,
            @RequestParam(value = "language", required = false, defaultValue = "en") String language) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(getTemplate(language), name));
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/rest/greetMeObj", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Greeting sayHello(
            @RequestBody(required = true) Input input) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                String.format(getTemplate(input.getLanguage()), input.getName()));
    }

    private String getTemplate(String language) {
        String template;
        switch (language) {
        case "nl":
        case "NL":
            template = TEMPLATE_NL;
            break;
        case "fr":
        case "FR":
            template = TEMPLATE_FR;
            break;
        case "en":
        case "EN":
        default:
            template = TEMPLATE_EN;
            break;
        }
        return template;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's just a WARN, so you can ignore it? Or does this warning result in another error?

Comment: apparently you cannot do a post with jsonp for cross domain request

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess the solution is described here: [Why SpringMVC Request method 'GET' not supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333611/why-springmvc-request-method-get-not-supported)

Both values in the RequestMapping has to be the same. So for each value you have to define one for GET and one for POST.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/rest/greetMe", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Greeting sayHello(
        @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "Stranger") String name,
        @RequestParam(value = "language", required = false, defaultValue = "en") String language) {
    return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(getTemplate(language), name));
}

@RequestMapping(value="/rest/greetMe", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Greeting sayHello(
        @RequestBody(required = true) Input input) {
    return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
            String.format(getTemplate(input.getLanguage()), input.getName()));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Check your controller, if you have mapped any of these calls to default mapping:

```
    @DeleteMapping()
    @PostMapping()
    @GetMapping()
```

It is mapped to `path="/"`. Please change it to

```
    @DeleteMapping(path="/something")
    @PostMapping(path="/something")
    @GetMapping(path="/something")
```