# How to convert a GET request to POST

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring-mvc

I don't know if it is possible or not. I referred some site, but I didn't get exact answer.

```
I am using 
<a href="xyz?id=4"> click </a>
```

When I send this request to server in the response page easily I can see **"id=4"** in address bar, obviously which is not secure, But in post request we cant see this.

So can we convert a get request to post or ant other way is there to hide this from address bar.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use a form with action and method post

Comment: no I can't, use form. @guradio

Comment: send an ajax request with type post.

Comment: Ya this is possible but I want the result in a different page. @guradio

Comment: A link will always be sent as a GET request. If you can't change how you make the request, you are out of luck. *"in post request we cant see this."* it's not visible in the URL but unless you use HTTPS it's still easily interceptable.

Comment: @MickeyPatel You can still use jquery or form POST and get the result on a different page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="#" onclick="postForm()"> click </a>
```

Dynamically create a from and post it.

```
function postForm() {
var form = $('<form method="POST" action="xyz"></form>');
$(document.body).append(form);
form.append('<input type="hidden" name="id" value="4"/>');
form.submit();
}
```

As Racil suggested in comments, you can also do the following

```
<a href="#" id="postLink"> click </a>
```

and then

```
$('#postLink').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   //create form and post
});
```

Comment: Nice, but I wouldn't use both `href` and `onclick`. I'd use `<a href="javascript:void postForm();">click</a>`.

Comment: @RacilHilan yes or bind anchor's id to bind click event with `href='#'`

Comment: @anu don't know why but $(document).append(form); line is not working.

Comment: @MickeyPatel Try `$("body").append(form)` or `$(document.body)`

Comment: What you told that is working fine, but after redirecting the response to a page when I am trying to hit the enter button in address bar it is sowing me this error "HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported"  @anu

Comment: Looks like some [spring related problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3333611/456135), which I am not good at. Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3333611/456135) or post a separate question

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, to convert `GET` to `POST`, simply change the link to a form:

```
<form id="myForm" action="xyz" method="post">
  <input type"hidden" name="id" value="4"/>
</form>
```

This form will not be visible and you can easily auto-submit it using JavaScript in your link:

```
<a href="javascript:void document.getElementById('myForm').submit();"> click </a>
```

Secondly and more importantly, both `GET` and `POST` are equally not secure over HTTP. To secure them, use HTTPS and they will be both equally secure, so no need to change if `GET` is working for you.

Comment: Isn't the default method GET for submitting a form?

Comment: @fbo3264 Oops! Corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Call a java script function on onclick which will make the form submission using post method or you can use ajax call to post the data and get your desired results.Use id as a parameter in function.

```
<a href="#" onclick="postData(4)">

/// Javascript function for ajax call
function postData(id){
  var param = { "Id": id};
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "xyz.aspx",
    data: JSON.stringify(param),
    success: function (data) {
         /// Recive data here or do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Make a form having single input type hidden and onclick set value of that input type hidden element and submit form using jquery.

```
<form id="target" action="destination.html">
   <input type="hidden" id="hiddenValue">
</form>

/// Javascript function for setting value of hidden element and form submission using jquery
    function postData(id){
       $("#hiddenValue").val(id);
       $("#target").submit();
    }
```

Hopefully this will solve your problem.