# In Jersey can I convert a GET to POST on the server?

Tags: java, rest, url, jersey

I am working on:

Java web application
Jersey/rest
Java 8

I have a list of entities, and for each entity the user has a link to create a sub-entity on the server (the values for the sub entity are computed on the server and require no user input).

I have a web page with something like this:

```
Entity 1
<a href=".../entity/1/subentity">Create sub</a>

Entity 2
Sub Already Exists

Entity 3
<a href=".../entity/2/subentity">Create sub</a>

...
```

However, I think according to REST this should be a PUT/POST instead of a GET. Do I really need to replace all these links with a form wrapped around each one to get around this issue?

Is there a way in Jersey to convert these GETs to PUTs on the server the way you can with HttpMethodOverrideFilter for POSTS?

**EDIT:**
This web application will not publicly available.

Comment: Write your own filter. But BEWARE OF CRAWLERS!

Comment: Using a POST instead of a GET has good, technical and semantic reasons: browsers and proxies are not supposed to retry such requests because they're not idempotent, crawlers are not supposed to submit post forms, proxies are not supposed to cache the responses, etc. "Transforming" a POST into a GET at server-side doesn't make much sense, and defeats the purpose of using a POST.

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet, just to clarify I was considering transforming a GET to a PUT, just in case that makes any difference.

Comment: If you request consists in creating something, and is not idempotent, a POST is the right method.

Comment: It is creating something but it is non-idempotent so I am leaning toward PUT.

Comment: So the solution I am now considering is to use links, however clicking the links would submit a form (as per this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37583932/how-to-convert-a-get-request-to-post) which is dynamically generated so as not to clutter the html with a ton of forms. Then using `HttpMethodOverrideFilter` I can override this POST to become PUT.

Comment: If the requests are sent as GETs through the network, there is no sense to convert them to PUT or POST on server. The fact if it's converted to a PUT or POST on the server won't make any difference.

Comment: Thanks @pcjuzer . In this approach the request would be sent as a POST through the network (not GET) because of the JavaScript. The given that forms don't support PUT I think its fairly common to convert to PUT using `HttpMethodOverrideFilter`

Comment: I've read in Javadoc that HttpMethodOverrideFilter is for cases when proxies don't let in PUT/DELETE method. Additionally, doesn't this filter require a special HTTP header, like X-HTTP-Method-Override?  In your case, wouldn't it be fine to simply use @POST JAX-RS annotation on the endpoint?

Comment: @POST would do I think, but PUT describes it slightly better in my situation. I think you have two approaches and the header is one. The other is just to append ?_method=PUT to the URL which strikes me as easier.